# Keeping node_modules up to date in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

I'm working with a team on a repo built in Docker and Node. When someone else installs node packages, I `git pull` those changes to `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

I can't just run `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`, though, to install these new node packages. I have to first `docker-compose down -v`. This is because we're using a volume to store the node modules. We're not tied to this, and frankly would rather just store the modules in a docker image layer. But then, when we bind the app volume (`- .:/app` in `docker-compose.yml`), the `node_modules` folder in the image is shadowed.

It feels like we're taking the wrong approach to this, but this seems to be what the generally accepted practice is. Our setup is based on "[Lessons from Building a Node App in Docker](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html)"

Our `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:8.4.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --loglevel=error --progess=false
COPY . /app/
```

Our `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
version: '2.1'

services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: main
    command: ['node', 'index.js']
```

My understanding of the issue is that, in the `docker-compose.yml` file, The volume `- /app/node_modules` creates a volume that *copies* the node modules from inside the image layer into a volume, meaning that when we build the app again with a different `package.json`, the image is updated but not the volume. `down`ing the volume forces it to re-copy from the updated image `node_modules`, which is why that works. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect :)

We're running in AWS ECS, so unfortunately we can only use docker features available in 17.03.2-ce (no multi-stage docker files for now).

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538187/docker-compose-v3-named-volume-node-modules-from-npm-install?rq=1, though it doesn't have an answer

Comment: Also potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916101/keeping-node-modules-up-to-date-in-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but in case anyone else comes here with the same issue, I struggled with this too and this is how I could achieve the desired behaviour:

```bash
docker-compose up --build --renew-anon-volumes
```

According to the documentation on `docker-compose up` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/

| Option | Short | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| --renew-anon-volumes | -V | Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving data from the previous containers. |

With this, you not only build a new image, but also override the original volume used to store `node_modules`. Note that it doesn't work with named volumes. If you use named volumes, you'd need to manually remove that volume with `docker volume rm <volume-name>` before running `docker-compose up` again.

The understanding of how volumes work from the original question seems sound. Readers may also find the following discussion in the Github issue beneficial to understanding it.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30647#issuecomment-276882545

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you map the current folder to /app in container. I would erase ./node_modules if it exists in current folder, before doing docker-compose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, when I try this, the node_modules folder gets created again in my current (local) folder, on the line `RUN npm install --loglevel=error --progess=false`. Would I need to remove the node_modules folder every time? (Or is that possible to do using the dockerfile?)

Comment: I would try to add RUN rm -rf ./node_modules || true, before RUN npm install command line.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I think because it's removing the `node_modules` folder in the image, but the volume is still persisting with the old copy of the data from the first time it was built.